# no special files in /dev/ after partition created with parted

Tags: parted

I've created two partitions with parted:

```
mklabel gpt
mkpart primary ext4 1 80%
mkpart primary ext4 80% -1
```

after reboot these are *properly* shown

```
parted /dev/sdc print
Model: easyRAID  Q12 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3999GB  3999GB               primary
 2      3999GB  4999GB  1000GB               primary
```

However there are no device files sdc1 and sdc2 in /dev/ directory. I can try `mknod` but I'm not sure what parameters should I use.

Of course, as there are no /dev/sdc1-2, so when I try to create DRBD on these I see  following message:

```
drbdadm create-md homes
open(/dev/sdc1) failed: No such file or directory
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/sdc1 internal create-md' terminated with exit code 20
```

Can somebody explain me why `parted` hasn't created these node-files and how should I proceed safely?

I'm working on clean installed CentOS 5.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading I found it.

One need to start `partprobe` to create the nodes files. After this step I could also start with creation of the DRBD-device.